# Why does aggregation function does not work in my laravel SQL Query?

Tags: php, mysql, eloquent, laravel-5

```
$year = date("y"); 
for($i=1;$i<=12;$i++) 
{ 
   $MonthlyReceive = DB::table('order_items') ->whereBetween('created_at',array($year.'-'.$i.'-1',$year.'-'.$i.'-31')) ->select(DB::raw('sum(price*quantity)'))->where('quantity','<','0');
   return $MonthlyReceive; 
}

// table name "order_items"
// id |product_id |quantity |price |order_id
```

Comment: I want per month total receiving amount, so please give me a solution in this for loop.

Comment: What's the error or unexpected behaviour you receive?

Comment: receiving: [[{sum(price*quantity): null}], [{sum(price*quantity): null}], [{sum(price*quantity): null}],…]
0: [{sum(price*quantity): null}]
0: {sum(price*quantity): null}
1: [{sum(price*quantity): null}]
2: [{sum(price*quantity): null}]
3: [{sum(price*quantity): null}]
4: [{sum(price*quantity): null}]
5: [{sum(price*quantity): null}]
6: [{sum(price*quantity): null}]
7: [{sum(price*quantity): null}]
8: [{sum(price*quantity): null}]
9: [{sum(price*quantity): null}]
10: [{sum(price*quantity): -16800}]
11: [{sum(price*quantity): null}]

Comment: its work on array 11 value is okay but does not show in my dasgboard graph

Comment: @sr_atiq If possible please add your error with some explanation, It's better for understanding.

Comment: How are you executing the query?

Comment: Already solved. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$year = date("y");
for($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) {
    $MonthlyReceive = DB::table('order_items')
        ->whereBetween('created_at', array($year.'-'.$i.'-1',$year.'-'.$i.'-31'))
        ->where('quantity', '>', '0')
        ->sum(DB::raw('price*quantity'));
    return $MonthlyReceive;
}
```

I have fixed it by using this code.

Comment: Great! But try to avoid the loop. I'm also working like this and without loop.

Comment: @er.irfankhan11 Ok I will try to avoid the loop. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

You can get aggregated data monthly wise without the loop.

```
   $MonthlyReceive = DB::table('order_items')
                ->select(DB::raw('sum(price*quantity) as amnt'))
                ->whereRaw('date(created_at) between "'.$year.'-01-01" and "'.$year.'-12-31"')
                ->where('quantity','<','0')
                ->groupBy(DB::raw("date_format(created_at, '%Y-%M')"));
```

Just use `group by` with aggregation function.

Comment: not working yet. and loop is needed your formate show me only January values